# Как программно сменить представление?

Tags: xcode, objective-c

Приветствую!

Третий день уже ищу я, как программно сменить представление (экраны). Не могли бы вы объяснить мне это или же указать на источник, где бы я мог почерпнуть эти знания.

Требуется из функции вызвать метод перехода на другое представление (экран).
В своем проекте я использую storyboard, segue'и создавать уже умею.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А так пробовал?

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:<#(NSString *)#> sender:<#(id)#>]
```